# Will I lose performance by specifying a value that I might not use in a dynamic component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my app, I have 10 components, all of which require a property called `andamento`; but only a subset require a property called `custas`.

If I set the `custas` property for *all* components in `andamentosOrdenado` (below), will I lose performance versus setting the property for only a subset?

Here is my code:

```
<v-timeline-item class="mb-3" small v-for="andamento in andamentosOrdenado" :key="andamento.nome">
  <component v-bind:is="andamento.form" :andamento="andamento" :custas="notificacao.custas"></component>
</v-timeline-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `custas` is static/constant:

> No, because you can't *"lose"* performance for **not** using a constant value/variable, this is because the property has already been defined and it's value has already been evaluated (a process that doesn't need to happen again).

If the value of `custas` isn't static/constant:

> Then yes, because you're making the machine waste resources on evaluating a non-static value that you're most likely not going to use. Not to mention that this value *might* change, meaning it's value would be re-evaluated (for no reason).

An alternative solution to this problem would be to use an `if` statement to define the `custas` property conditionally, for example:

```
// pseudo code:
if (i_need_custas) {
  my_object.custas = fn_that_returns_value_that_might_change();
}
```

Then, where you need to use `custas`:

```
// pseudo code:
if (my_object.hasOwnProperty("custas")) {
  // do stuff with custas
}
```

Good luck.